# Ruby on Rails - Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to create relationship between student, courses and enrolment.

One student can enrol in only one course.
A course can be enrolled by many students.

How to acheive this ?

I was able to create has_many_through relationship like this

```
class
  Student < User
    has_many :enrollments
    has_many :course , through: :enrollments
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :enrollments
    has_many :students, through: :enrollments, class_name: "User"
end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :course
end
```

But this works only for has_many on both the sides of students and courses.
But I want only one student to enrol in one course like this

```
class Student < User
    has_one :enrollment
    has_one :course , through: :enrollment
end
```

But this does not work. When I do this

```
Student.first.enrollment.create(course: Course.last)
```

I get an error like this

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `enrollment' for #<Student:0x007f7ff8baf4a8>
```

Comment: I assume you try to do it in the console. Did you restart your console (or type `reload!`) after you changed the file?

Comment: Thanks. I tried reload! but did not work.

Comment: But this worked. Have to use enrolments (plural) `Student.first.enrollments.create(course: Course.last)`

Comment: Again: Is the error message the same? Or is it undefined method `create` on nil?

Comment: But still student is able to enrol in many courses. How to restrict a student to enrol in only one course

Comment: There is no error message in console when more than one courses are enrolled by a student.

Comment: There won't be with only `has_one` - `has_one` association doesn't ensure that the student will be connected with only one enrollment. If you want to have this, you should use validations on the `Enrollment` side, I guess.

Comment: yes you are right . It works now with the use of validation `validates :student , uniqueness: true`  and using has_many instead of has_one

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marek Lipka for suggesting this solution.

Add validation in Enrollment

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :course

    validates :student , uniqueness: true
end
```

And use has_many enrollments

```
class Student < User
    has_many :enrollments
    has_many :course , through: :enrollments
end
```